# I trying to exit but getting an exception bad argument called as exit(undefined,kill)

Tags: erlang

I'm trying to write a function which simply kills my program. It is called quitChat. However I get this error when I call the function `messenger:quitChat()`.

```erlang
** exception error: bad argument
    in function  exit/2
        called as exit(undefined,kill)
    in call from messenger:quitChat/0 (messenger.erl, line 26)
```

So far I am using this code:

```
-module(messenger).
-export([start_server/0, server/1, logon/1, logoff/0, message/2, client/2,
requestChat/1, quitChat/0]).

server_node() ->
    messenger@timberlake.

server(User_List) ->
    receive
        {From, logon, Name} ->
            New_User_List = server_logon(From, Name, User_List),
            server(New_User_List);
        {From, logoff} ->
            New_User_List = server_logoff(From, User_List),
            server(New_User_List);
        {From, message_to, To, Message} ->
            server_transfer(From, To, Message, User_List),
            io:format("list is now: ~p~n", [User_List]),
            server(User_List)
    end.

start_server() ->
    register(messenger, spawn(messenger, server, [[]])).

quitChat() ->
    exit(whereis(messenger), kill).
```

Comment: What do you get when you call `whereis(messenger)` in your erlang REPL?

Comment: I get a pid @dethron5000

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `erlang:halt/0,1`.

[Documentation](http://erldocs.com/current/erts/erlang.html?i=0&search=halt#halt/0)

Answer (score 0):

Change your quitChat in this way:

```
quitChat() ->
   case whereis(messenger) of
      undefined -> ok; % No registered process with name messenger
      Pid -> exit(Pid, kill)
   end.
```